# ColdFusion Cookie/Form Submission Loophole

Tags: html, browser, coldfusion

Okay so here is my problem. I have developed a framework which does the following:

If, for example, you have four webpages... but you only want to allow users to reach the "4th" webpage after progressing through pages 1-3 sequentially - I have built this functionality (basically I set an encrypted cookie keeping track of what the user has completed thus allowing to know what they should be able to access). There are two parts of it:

1) If a page does NOT have a quiz, the user must only visit the webpages sequentially to be allowed to view the 4th page in the "progression".

2) However, if a page has a quiz on it, the user must successfully pass the quiz to go on to the next sequential page.

Now... Here is the real biggie... The last page will often be a web form which, obviously, I only want an individual to fill out and submit if they have reached the form by sequentially getting to that last page in the progression... BUT I found a flaw in the system. If someone were to go completely through the progression and fill the form out... they could delete their browser's "form data" and go "back" to the form and allow a friend to fill the form out. That would be detrimental to the system, and the users who will be navigating this progression are GOING to look for ways to get around going through it.

Some of the suggestions I will probably get will not be possible given the larger framework I am in, but rather than list all of the impossibilities I would like to see what you guys thought would be a way of getting around this issue?

P.S. This functionality is built in HTML and ColdFusion.

Thank you for any feedback, it is a great help!

EDIT: 
Keep in mind the user must be able to back track any previous page they already completed.

Comment: Why a cookie and not a session variable? I think using a session variable and possibly a server-side "checklist" or data records would lock this down. This wouldn't stop them from accessing it, only tracking that they have completed it. You could flip the display from a from to a read-only output of their entered data.

Comment: Well, mostly because I cannot override our default session timeout time which is defined by the application. However, my cookie I set cannot be hijacked, it is encrypted with AES. Also, what do you mean by, "You could flip the display from a from to a read-only output of their entered data."

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno Well, I suppose the cookie could be injected into... they could just copy the encrypted value... Never thought about that... wow... am I screwed?

Comment: "Read only output": you check if there is a record that the user already completed a page or form and if so, show what they input rather than the form. You can still reuse the forms for other instances of this "workflow".

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno Basically if they submitted the form, only show what they submitted rather than the form again. I get that, and I could do that. However, what about in the case where the cookie's encypted value says they have completed pages 1-3 (not yet 4). If users got curious, they could copy they encrypted value into their friend's cookie and that person would be a 3/4 progress as well.

Comment: You need something going on server-side. When a progression starts, you need to create a row in the database, pass the id of that back, and use that in the cookie (or preferably session) variable. Every page in the progression should check the status of the row and the cookie/session variable needs to be checked.

Comment: @cfqueryparam If I were doing this session (server-side) based instead of the cookie route, I still would not save anything in the database. Essentially the session would take care of all of this as the session would be unique and I could just implement Adrian's idea and be good to go. However, currently, user A's cookie will look identical to user B's cookie at any arbitrary step in the process (in other words, if two different users have both completed 2/4 their cookies will look identical) - thus my encryption really doesn't do much... the values need to be unique.

Comment: Well.. I might have an idea... This sounds so dirty though because it would be using sessions which I was trying to avoid in the first place... I could use the user's session id in the encryption cookie process... However, then their ID will only last as long as their session (this is meant for anonymous users to be able to complete) - but that's the only way I can think of... Any ideas on that?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno - Hey, I took your suggestion to making it all session based on the server rather than client-side cookie based. But have two small things to consider now that I have done that and would appreciate some insight if you have time... 1) When I show the  submitted form(via a session var check) rather than the form itself again, what if the user filled the form out incorrectly? Do they just have to traverse the page set again? 2) Also, should I be concerned with session timing out and a user losing their progress (note: I'm not going to save user progress in a the db)